# Kentico 9 ui permissions regarding the media library

Tags: kentico

is it possible to allow read access only to the media library? I'm setting a role and with the Media Library module, I've only set the Read permission to Allow, but a user with that role still sees the upload button. Am I looking at the wrong module?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the specific Media Library and then edit. 
Then you will see the list of files within the media library. 
On the left-hand side, there will be '...', hover over this and then click on Security.

Here you can specify which role you want to perform what action in that specific Media Library.

Comment: Ilesh, I think in Kentico 9, when you edit Media Library there is Security tab on the left. Other than that you suggestion should do what Mark needs.

Comment: I have my editor role as only 'See library content'. user logs in, can still see the upload, then get's a alert error, access to path denied. Please don't tell me that the upload button is there regardless.

Comment: This looks like how Kentico deals with it as default. What you could do is look deeper into the code and look at the Media Library files to hide that button for a specific role.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure Permissions and UI Personalization?

Comment: That's where i started.

Answer (score 0):

So in this case, I removed access to the media library. It forces editors to add images as attachments, which was my end goal. Reason being, sync only works with published content, and won't migrate files from one server to another.